# Installing Windows 7 on Asus Essentio Series Desktop

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, drivers

I have installed Windows 7 in Windows 8 Asus Essentio Desktop. On boot up I can choose which OS
I want. Only problem I can't install LAN Drivers that work Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller.
Downloaded drivers for windows 7 OS says driver not digitally signed. Does work
Also USB XHCI Compliant Host Controller same problem. I understand that's only for Windows *.
Can I solve this problem? If Not will this machine Install Windows 7 successfully?

Comment: Have you tried installing anyway, you can install drivers that are not digitally signed.

Answer (score 0):

Install the drivers anyway, assuming they came from the realtek website. It should fix your problem. If it does not work it may be a bad installation, as windows 8 computers do not play well with windows 7 unless all of the hidden bios options are changed (which you were apparently able to figure out).

Comment: Thanks it worked downloading from Realtek. Previously installed from

Comment: Windows would not allow installation of drivers not digitally signed